# Firebase dynamic link API - How to update social image and keep same short link url

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using the follow code to create a short link and it works fine.
However if I want to update the social image and give it a longDynamicLink that is exactly the same as the original except the social image url it creates a new short link.
This means all the previous short links need to be replaced with the new short link and some of these are printed on QR codes.

How can I retain the original short link?

Note: If I do this in the Firebase console I can change the social image and keep the same short link. In fact I can change any parameter and keep the same short link.

```
const options = { 
    method: 'POST',
    uri: `https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=${firebaseProjectApiKey}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
      "longDynamicLink": dynamicLinkUrl,
      "suffix": {
        "option": "SHORT"
      }
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently via the API but may be in the future.
Other options would be to:

1. Use the long dynamic link https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually
2. Use a 3rd party or custom url shortener

From google support:

> To give an overview, we received similar requests regarding a REST API
> that would allow developers to edit short links created
> programmatically or the REST API, and I agree that it would bring more
> value to the Dynamic Links service as a whole. As an action, I have
> added this case into the list, so our engineers will know that many
> developers, such as yourself, would like FDL to support this feature.

Comment: How using long dynamic links allows to update existing links? Docs do not mention any API for that.